# Get the average over the next 5 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Query that Calculates the avg for measurements by day 
now i would like to have for each row the avg from across the next 5 days from that

oh... I'm using Sql Server

Here is what i have

```
SELECT Cast(Cast (Datepart(year, Dateadd(minute, (a.quarternumber * 15), 
            '2000-01-01')) 
                   AS 
            VARCHAR(4)) 
            + '-' 
            + Cast (Datepart(month, Dateadd(minute, (a.quarternumber * 15), 
                   '2000-01-01')) 
            AS VARCHAR(4)) 
            + '-' 
            + Cast (Datepart(day, Dateadd(minute, (a.quarternumber * 15), 
            '2000-01-01') 
                   )AS 
            VARCHAR(4)) 
            + ' ' AS DATETIME) AS [TimeStamp], 
       --AVG(a.value) over(order by a.value) as exper, 
       Round(Avg(a.value), 2)  AS Value 
FROM   measurements.archive a 
       INNER JOIN measurements.points p 
               ON a.pointid = p.id 
       INNER JOIN fifthcore..cm_lod_devices ld 
               ON ld.uuid = p.logicaldeviceuuid 
WHERE  ld.id IN (SELECT value 
                 FROM   @LodDeviceIds) 
       AND p.name = @Name 
       AND a.quarternumber BETWEEN @ChartBeginNumber AND @ChartEndNumber 
GROUP  BY Datepart(year, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01') 
), 
          Datepart(month, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01' 
                          )), 
          Datepart(day, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01')) 
ORDER  BY Datepart(day, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01'))
```

I whas looking into something like this, but just can't get it to work

```
AVG(y) OVER(ORDER BY x
3 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)


Table                             :extra column that would avg the result of next five days 
2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 16.780000   --> 15.8 
2014-07-02 00:00:00.000 15.940000   --> 16 
2014-07-03 00:00:00.000 16.790000
2014-07-04 00:00:00.000 16.790000
2014-07-05 00:00:00.000 16.040000
2014-07-06 00:00:00.000 16.500000
2014-07-07 00:00:00.000 16.790000
2014-07-08 00:00:00.000 16.790000
2014-07-09 00:00:00.000 16.790000
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: ah,  im using  SQL Server

Comment: I've tagged your question accordingly. When you ask future questions, please add the tag for your RDBMS in addition to the SQL tag (since the answers are often vendor-specific).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using `AVG()` With the `OVER` clause incorrectly.

You are using `GROUP BY` - and therefore `AVG()` in the same query will apply to the group, not the entire data set, hence you can't use the SQL SERVER 2012 specific windowing version without first doing a subquery or CTE.

Here's how I think you could make it work, but note - I've not actually tested it at this point.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Cast(Cast (Datepart(year, Dateadd(minute, (a.quarternumber * 15), 
                '2000-01-01')) 
                       AS 
                VARCHAR(4)) 
                + '-' 
                + Cast (Datepart(month, Dateadd(minute, (a.quarternumber * 15), 
                       '2000-01-01')) 
                AS VARCHAR(4)) 
                + '-' 
                + Cast (Datepart(day, Dateadd(minute, (a.quarternumber * 15), 
                '2000-01-01') 
                       )AS 
                VARCHAR(4)) 
                + ' ' AS DATETIME) AS [TimeStamp], 
           Round(Avg(a.value), 2)  AS Value
           SUM (a.value) AS ValueSum, -- New item - required for calculating windowed average from group
           COUNT(a.value) AS ValueCount  -- New item - required for calculating windowed average from group
    FROM   measurements.archive a 
           INNER JOIN measurements.points p 
                   ON a.pointid = p.id 
           INNER JOIN fifthcore..cm_lod_devices ld 
                   ON ld.uuid = p.logicaldeviceuuid 
    WHERE  ld.id IN (SELECT value 
                     FROM   @LodDeviceIds) 
           AND p.name = @Name 
           AND a.quarternumber BETWEEN @ChartBeginNumber AND @ChartEndNumber 
    GROUP  BY Datepart(year, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01') 
    ), 
              Datepart(month, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01' 
                              )), 
              Datepart(day, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01')) 
    ORDER  BY Datepart(day, Dateadd(minute, ( a.quarternumber * 15 ), '2000-01-01'))
)
SELECT 
    [TimeStamp],
    Value,
    SUM(ValueSum) OVER (
        ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING
    ) /
    SUM(ValueCount) OVER (
        ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING
    ) AS ValueOverNext5 
    -- Average = SUM(x) / COUNT(x) = SUM(SUM(group)) / SUM(COUNT(group))
FROM cte
```

As you can see I put your query inside a common table expression, and added 2 new columns for SUM and COUNT. Then I applied the windowed AVG OVER to these items (by doing SUM(total) OVER (...) / SUM(count) OVER (...) - a straight AVG of the already averaged values from the CTE would be incorrect)

Hopefully that makes sense and works!

Answer (score 1):

This is if you are SQL Server 2008
The first part just makes the test data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    MyDate DATETIME,
    Value DECIMAL(19,6)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
('2014-07-01 00:00:00.000',16.780000),
('2014-07-02 00:00:00.000',15.940000), 
('2014-07-03 00:00:00.000',16.790000),
('2014-07-04 00:00:00.000',16.790000),
('2014-07-05 00:00:00.000',16.040000),
('2014-07-06 00:00:00.000',16.500000),
('2014-07-07 00:00:00.000',16.790000),
('2014-07-08 00:00:00.000',16.790000),
('2014-07-09 00:00:00.000',16.790000);
```

Now I create a CTE order my data and give it a rownumber.

```
WITH SortedData AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyDate) RN
    FROM @MyTable
)
```

Now using my CTE, I get the next 4 rows to avg with.

```
SELECT 
CAST(t1.MyDate AS DATE) AS MyDate,
t1.Value,
t1.RN,
d.FCNT,
d.FSUM,
d.FAVG
FROM SortedData T1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(T2.VALUE)  FSUM,
        COUNT(1) FCNT,
        AVG(T2.Value) FAVG
    FROM SortedData T2
    WHERE T2.RN >= T1.RN
        AND T2.RN <= T1.RN + 4
) d
ORDER BY T1.RN
```

Here is the output:

```
MyDate  Value   RN  FCNT    FSUM    FAVG
2014-07-01  16.780000   1   5   82.340000   16.468000
2014-07-02  15.940000   2   5   82.060000   16.412000
2014-07-03  16.790000   3   5   82.910000   16.582000
2014-07-04  16.790000   4   5   82.910000   16.582000
2014-07-05  16.040000   5   5   82.910000   16.582000
2014-07-06  16.500000   6   4   66.870000   16.717500
2014-07-07  16.790000   7   3   50.370000   16.790000
2014-07-08  16.790000   8   2   33.580000   16.790000
2014-07-09  16.790000   9   1   16.790000   16.790000
```

For SQL Server 2012 it could be as easy as this: 
Lets change up the test data and put some more rows for each date:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    MyDate DATETIME,
    Value DECIMAL(19,6)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
('2014-07-01 00:00:00.000',1.0),
('2014-07-01 00:00:00.000',2.0),
('2014-07-01 00:00:00.000',3.0),
('2014-07-01 00:00:00.000',4.0),
('2014-07-02 00:00:00.000',7.0),
('2014-07-02 00:00:00.000',7.0),
('2014-07-02 00:00:00.000',7.0),
('2014-07-03 00:00:00.000',8.0),
('2014-07-04 00:00:00.000',9.0),
('2014-07-05 00:00:00.000',10.0),
('2014-07-06 00:00:00.000',11.0),
('2014-07-07 00:00:00.000',20.0),
('2014-07-08 00:00:00.000',25.0),
('2014-07-09 00:00:00.000',50.0);
```

Now lets make our CTE group and AVG the data:

```
WITH SortedData AS
(
    SELECT
        MyDate,
        AVG(VALUE) DayAvg,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyDate) RN,
        AVG(AVG(VALUE)) OVER (ORDER BY MyDate ROWS between current row and 4 following) FDAVG
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY MyDate
)

SELECT CAST(sd.MyDate AS DATE) AS MyDate,
    sd.DayAvg,
    sd.RN,
    sd.FDAVG
FROM SortedData sd
```

Here is the output:

```
MyDate  DayAvg  RN  FDAVG
2014-07-01  2.500000    1   7.300000
2014-07-02  7.000000    2   9.000000
2014-07-03  8.000000    3   11.600000
2014-07-04  9.000000    4   15.000000
2014-07-05  10.000000   5   23.200000
2014-07-06  11.000000   6   26.500000
2014-07-07  20.000000   7   31.666666
2014-07-08  25.000000   8   37.500000
2014-07-09  50.000000   9   50.000000
```

Comment: thats a great answer, but is it also possible to skip rows instead of between ?

Comment: yes, for instance if you wanted the next 3 rows AFTER your current row you could put AVG(AVG(VALUE)) OVER (ORDER BY MyDate ROWS between 1 following and 3 following) but the last row would return null because there wouldn't be any rows after it to avg.

Comment: Thanks ,  "ROWS between 1 following and 3 following" that worked for me.